# How to start clock task using passenger & nginx on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I deploy my project using **passenger** & **nginx** & **Amazon EC2**.

How can i run clock task on server. I used [Clockwork gem](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork).

This is my clock task (lib/clock.rb) :

```
# require boot & environment for a Rails app
require_relative "../config/boot"
require_relative "../config/environment"

require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork

  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every 10.minutes, 'send detail' do
    ::User.periodically_send_detail
  end
end
```

Locally i can run `bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb` and it's working. It send detail on every 10 seconds.

On heroku i add `bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb` to Procfile like (NOTE: extra charge will be applied for clock) :

```
clock:  bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

Works on heroku also.

**But how can i run this clock file with passenger and nginx and Amazon EC2 server on production startup ?**

Any extra information required then tell me i will provide.

Comment: if you are able to ssh on your server then use `nohub` as `nohup command-name &` and in your case `nohup  bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb &`.(nohup Execute Commands After You Exit From a Shell Prompt)

Comment: @NitinKumar, Thanks for this solution. I able  to ssh on my server and tried your solution but got this after run nohup command `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’`

Comment: That's not an error - it's normal behavior. It just informs you that once started the in/output is removed from your console...please check your `send detail` will be running.

Comment: @NitinKumar, I tried your solution but not get success. So i tried with `whenever gem` and i got success. I describe my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I access server via SSH.

I change gem to `whenever gem` and it doing job well.

Add to gem file :

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

Then run `wheneverize .`

Then add task to config/schedule.rb fiile :

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "User.periodically_send_student_detail", :output => 'cron.log'
end
```

Then update your crontab in ubuntu server using this command :

```
$ whenever --update-crontab --set environment='production'
```

and that's it. It's done.

You can check cronjob using this command `crontab -e OR crontab -l`